# Generate static HTML files from ejs templates

Tags: node.js, express, ejs

OK, so I have my basic nodejs website up and running. It's all working and runs through a node server - using my [basic-node-site](https://github.com/andrewbrandwood/node-basic-site)

It uses ejs as the templating engine.

I'd like to release these templates as a static website.  So all generated locally and it exports all my pages to static HTML files that I can publish on my basic hosting platform. no server side technology required.

I've had a look at jade, but it required me to change the templating and the structure.

Is there any tool out there that just publishes my current setup to a folder with all the generated html files??

Thanks for any help.  It's appreciated.

Answer (score 13):

As long as you have the EJS npm package installed you can compile it.

```
var fs = require('fs'),
    ejs = require("ejs");

function ejs2html(path, information) {
    fs.readFile(path, 'utf8', function (err, data) {
        if (err) { console.log(err); return false; }
        var ejs_string = data,
            template = ejs.compile(ejs_string),
            html = template(information);
        fs.writeFile(path + '.html', html, function(err) {
            if(err) { console.log(err); return false }
            return true;
        });  
    });
}

ejs2html(__dirname+"/index.ejs")
```

- Path: the location of the file, include `__dirname` or it wont work
- Information: the information to be compiled like `{users: ['bill','bob']}` (optional)

[EJS](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ejs)

[Reading file in NodeJS](https://docs.nodejitsu.com/articles/file-system/how-to-read-files-in-nodejs)

#### Edit

I made the code work and tested it, the ejs file will be compiled and written to the same directory with `.html` appended to the end.

Comment: I'm getting an error on the path of my file.

{ [Error: ENOENT, open '/views/index.ejs'] errno: -2, code: 'ENOENT', path: '/views/index.ejs' }

is the path the path to my ejs file?

where do I set the directory of the outputted html file?

Comment: I shall test and get back to you

Comment: @MJPinfield My requirement is exactly the same but I am using npm script, but not able to succeed. I am able to do it page by page but not by directory.