# Generate HTML files through Express/EJS/FS and serve them through Nginx instead of express

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, nginx, fs

Let's say we have a JSON:

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "title": "Title 1",
    "description": "Description 1"
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "title": "Title 2",
    "description": "Description 2"
  },
  {
    "id": 3,
    "title": "Title 3",
    "description": "Description 3"
  }
]
```

And an EJS file called index.ejs

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <body>
    <% data.forEach(item => { %>
    <h1><%- item.title %></h1>
    <p><%- item.description %></p>
    <% }) %>
  </body>
</html>
```

I can simply use this javascript code to render the data through express:

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();

const data = require("./data.json");

app.set("view engine", "ejs");

app.get("/", (req, res) => {
  res.render("index", { data });
});

app.listen(4000);
```

However, what if I want to create the 3 HTML pages instead and serve them through Nginx?
I could use `fs` to create the html files. But the question is, how can I create the 3 generated pages using EJS but render the pages through Nginx instead of node.js's `app.get()`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the data is static (it's known in advance and doesn't change), you can generate the HTML pages once as part of some build process  by writing a separate nodejs script that uses EJS to generate the HTML files and then save the generated HTML files to an nginx specific directory and let nginx serve the static web pages from there.

I've done something similar for a github.io web-site where I used a nodejs script and a template engine to pre-generate static HTML pages which were then served through github.io.  This allowed me to use the features of templates (common header, common footer, common styles, etc...) to generate a set of static HTML pages.  When I want to update the web pages, I can just update the templates and regenerate rather than manually editing every single HTML page.

If the data is dynamic, then nginx has no idea how to generate them as it doesn't directly support these types of template engines (which are designed for Javascript engines) so you would stick with serving EJS templates from nodejs.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your broad answer, I want to rebuild the HTML pages once there is a change, the data rendered is somehow static anyway. I'm working on a large scale website so I think serving content through Nginx as plain HTML files is whole alot faster than express, which will make a request to the database each time a page loads. Can you please elaborate on how I could convert the generated EJS pages into local HTML files?

Comment: @CedricHadjian - All the template engines have a Javascript interface for generating the HTML directly rather than using them with Express.  See the EJS [doc](https://ejs.co/#docs) for examples for how to generate HTML from templates without using Express.  Probably you create your own nodejs build program and use `ejs.renderFile(...)` and then write the generated output to a file and directory of your choosing where nginx can serve them from.  You collect the data that goes in the template and then pass that to `ejs.renderFile()` along with the path to the template file.

Comment: Thanks this was more than helpful!

Comment: Yes, thank you. Also, check out this link it's exactly what I wanted: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30976477/generate-static-html-files-from-ejs-templates

Comment: @CedricHadjian - That is the concept.  I think using `ejs.renderFile()` will save some steps.